# How do i specify a file upload in django to a folder in reference to one of the model fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following django models in my Document app

```
class Section(models.Model):    
    choices = (
            ('Haematology', 'Haematology'),
            ('BloodBank', 'BloodBank'),
            ('Bacteriology', 'Bacteriology'),
            ('Parasitoloty', 'Parasitoloty'),
            ('Chemistry', 'Chemistry'),
            ('Histopathology', 'Histopathology'),
            ('Serology', 'Serology'),
           ('Immunology', 'Immunology'),
        )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = choices)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Section"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sections"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)


class Document(models.Model, instance): 
    documentSection = models.ForeignKey(Section)    
    category = models.ForeignKey(DocumentCategory)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
    description = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True, default = '')
    documentFile = models.FileField(upload_to = 'uploads/' +  instance.documentSection.title)
    fileFormat = models.ForeignKey(FileFormat)
    uploaded = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, default=timezone.now)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, default=timezone.now)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

When i upload Documents i want then to be saved in a folder like 'uploads/documentSection/
or 'uploads/documentSection/%Y/%m/

My problem is i cant figure out how to take the value of the documentSection and parse it to upload_to = 'uploads/documentSection/

Comment: are you uploading the files through the Django Admin? or do you have a view where you process this?

Comment: I was still uploading them using the admin just to test if it works before i create the views. I will also want to functionality to work when uploading through the views when i will create an upload form

Comment: I have updated the upload_to = 'uploads/' +  instance.documentSection.title. Its failing to work